# How to place a UICollectionViewController in InterfaceBuilder

Tags: uicollectionview, xcode8

Since i've updated to Xcode 8, placing a UICollectionViewController next to a UIViewController results in the warning:

```
Misplaced Views
"Collection View:
 Expected: width=384, height=512
 Actual: width=375, height=667"
```

It is reproducible by:

1. Open a new project
2. Drag a UICollectionViewController next to the existing ViewController
3. Make a segue from the initial ViewController to the UICollectionViewController (Show)
4. And then the Document Outline gives the error.

Doing the same with a UITableViewController doesn't produce the warnings.

What am I missing? Help is very appreciated.